# multiple sql queries in jsp

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

This may be a bad practice, but I'm novice in creating jsp. I want to perform multiple updates - using the if statement. There are about 6 queries that I want to use, but I can't get the code to work. Is it possible to update more than one sql in jsp?

Here's my code:

```js
<html> //dbupdatetam.jsp
<head><title>Update Tamil page</title></head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.util.* , javax.sql.* , java.sql.*" %>
<% 
java.sql.Connection con = null;
java.sql.Statement s = null;
java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = null;

String var1 = request.getParameter("num1");
String var2 = request.getParameter("num2");

//int var3 = Integer.parseInt(var1);


String url= "jdbc:sqlserver://HOST;databaseName=dbname";
String id= "user";
String pass = "pwd";


try{


Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);
}catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
cnfex.printStackTrace();
}
String sql = "select Genre from tablename where id= '" + var1 + "'";
String sqlFic = "update tablename set StatusID='0', Status= 'Borrowed (" + var2 + ")' where id= '" + var1 + "'";

try{ //try start
 s = con.createStatement();
//pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
%>
<%
String retnValue = null;
if ( rs.next() ){ //while start
    retnValue = rs.getString(1);
}
%>
<p>String value is <%=retnValue%></p>
<% if ( retnValue != null) { //ifstart
%>
<p>String value is <%=retnValue%></p>
<%
try{ //try1start
 s = con.createStatement();
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sqlFic);
    int count = s.executeUpdate(sqlFic); 
%>
    <p>The update is successful.<%=count%> record updated successfully.</p>
 <%
} //try1end
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally{ //finallystart
if(rs!=null) rs.close();
if(s!=null) s.close();
if(con!=null) con.close();
}//finallyend
%>
<% } %>
<%
//} //whileend
%>
<%
} //tryend
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally { //finallystart
if(rs!=null) rs.close();
if(s!=null) s.close();
if(con!=null) con.close();
} //finallyend
%>

</body>
</html>
```

This is where I get the var1 and var2:

```js
        <FORM ACTION="tamupdate.jsp" METHOD="POST">
            Enter your Emp ID:
            <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="num1">
            <BR>
            <b>Please Enter your <b>correct</b> Employee ID as this is where the book you request will be sent.</b>
            <br><BR>
            Enter the ID of the book you'd like to check the availability:
            <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="num2">
            <BR><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Check Availability">
        </FORM><br><br>
        



<jsp:include page="dbupdatetam.jsp">
<jsp:param name="num1" value="bookid"/>
<jsp:param name="num2" value="empid"/>
</jsp:include>
```

This doesn't work! I am using tomcat localhost and running the jsp via Internet explorer (http://localhost:8080/filename.jsp). I get a blank screen while running this. I suspect there's an issue with the update query. Can anyone review this and tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not connecting to multiple database then there is no need to create two Connection Objects because you can achieve this requirement creating a single object. 
I found you are using executeQuery() method while updating the record. Use executeUpdate() method of Connection object while you are performing any DML operations. It returns an integer value.

Below is the working jsp code.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.* , javax.sql.* , java.sql.*" %>
<% 
Connection con = null;
java.sql.Statement s = null;
java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;

int var3 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
int var4 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));


String url= "***";
String id= "***";
String pass = "***";

try{


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);

}catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
cnfex.printStackTrace();

}
String sql = "select name from demo where id="+var3;
String sql1 = "update demo set name='XYZ' where id="+var4;

try{    //try start

    s = con.createStatement();
        rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
%>
<%
String retnValue = null;
if( rs.next() ){ //while start
    retnValue = rs.getString(1);
}
%>
<p>String value is <%=retnValue%></p>
<% if ( retnValue != null) { //ifstart
%>
<%
try{ //try1start

    int count = s.executeUpdate(sql1); 
%>
    <p>The update is successful.<%=count%> record updated successfully.</p>
 <%

} //try1end
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally{ //finallystart
if(rs!=null) rs.close();
if(s!=null) s.close();
if(con!=null) con.close();
}//finallyend
%>
<% } %>
<%
//} //whileend
%>
<%
} //tryend
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally { //finallystart
if(rs!=null) rs.close();
if(s!=null) s.close();
if(con!=null) con.close();
} //finallyend
%>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Badal. I'm using SQL Server, not mysql. so I changed your code just a bit, but still it's not working. I get a blank screen when I run this on the IE. I checked the DB to see if the update happened, but it didn't. Here's the updated one:

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

String sql = "select Genre from tablename where id= '" + var1 + "'";
String sql1 = "update tablename set StatusID='0', Status= 'Borrowed (" + var2 + ")' where id= '" + var1 + "'";

Comment: Are you passing values for var3, var4 variables declared in the earlier code?

Comment: Yes, instead of var3 and var4, I used var1 and var2.

Comment: Can you share your complete code again ?

Comment: Just edited the post again coz, I could not comment it here. Too long for a comment!

Comment: oh, and the following is also present in tamupdate.jsp:

<jsp:include page="dbupdatetam.jsp">
<jsp:param name="num1" value="bookid"/>
<jsp:param name="num2" value="empid"/>
</jsp:include>

Comment: I would suggest use print statement to debug and find out in which line of code it is not working. Because with MySQL I have executed this jsp file is working fine. So there must be some issue in the SQL queries.